# Generic Wrapper Class possible?

Tags: c#-3.0

On C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5, imagine there's an interface:

```
public interface INameable
{
  string Name {get;}
}
```

and many immutable classes that implement the interface.

I would like to have a single extension method

```
public static T Rename<T>(this T obj) where T : INameable
{ 
  ...
}
```

that returns a wrapped instance of the original object with just the name changed and all other property reads and method calls routed to the original object.

How to get a generic wrapper class for this, without implementing it for all INameable implementing types? Do you think that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, unless `T` is constrained to be an interface or to be a class with all members virtual, and this constraint isn't possible to specify at compile time (though you could write a runtime check if you're happy with that approach).

The reason you cannot do it for arbitrary types is that if you take an object of type `T` then you must return an object that is assignable to `T`. If I pass an object that looks as follows...

```
public sealed class SomeClass : INameable
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Abc { get; }
}
```

...then there is no way you can create another type that is assignable to `SomeClass`. Not using `Reflection.Emit` or any other method, because the type is sealed.

However, if you're happy with the restrictions that I've mentioned then you could use something like the Castle DynamicProxy framework to create a type that proxies the passed in object and intercepts the calls to either forward or re-implement as appropriate.

Comment: Looks like Castle DynamicProxy and LinFu do exactly what i need. I hope that C# will offer that functionality in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, it's possible, but it involves generating code in memory.

You can look at [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx).

Note that it will involve a lot of code.

That is, if I assume I understand you correctly.

Here's what I think you're asking for:

```
SomeNameableObject a1 = new SomeNameableObject("ThisIsTheFirstName");
SomeNameableObject a2 = a1.Rename("ThisIsTheSecondName");
// a1 works, still has the name ThisIsTheFirstName
// a2 works, but everything is routed to a1,
//    except for the name, which is ThisIsTheSecondName
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what i need, but i was apprehensive of someone proposing Reflection.Emit :-)